# Is there a hint on Dr. Valdez’s first name?

Tags: resonance

In one of the opening screens of [Resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_%28game%29), one that introduces Ray Abbot, a blogger who is investigating strange secret Antevorta database mainframe in a medical facility, he needs to log in into the mainframe, using one of its users’ login. He is able to hack into the Dr. R. Valdez’s e-mail, but everywhere I looked he is only referred by the first initial, such as in his e-mail handle — *rvaldez@…* But the mainframe usernames consist of three first letters of a given name followed by three first letters of a family name.

I was able to figure out those thre first letters, but I had to just try to think of names that start with an ‘R’, and the correct one did not come to me right away, and I just had to try to sort of brute force it going over the list of R-names alfabetically, trying out more common ones, and eventually stumbled upon proper combination:

> His name turned out to be Ramon Valdez, so the username was `ramval`.

I checked the hacked e-mails, notes in the smart-phone, dialogs with a secretary etc., but could not find mention of the good Dr.’s first name. Was there something I’ve missed, or my approach was the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the secretary's boss is **randomized**.

The normal solution to this puzzle is to find the e-mail username of the boss (in your case it was `rvaldez`) in the secretary's account. Using this username, you can then use the password cracker you used earlier to **get into his account**, where his full name will be displayed **at the top of the screen** - in your case, "Welcome Dr. Ramon Valdez".

With the help of the full name and the information about the mainframe username composition, you can then deduce the mainframe username.

Comment: Oh, sucks that I did not skeep the save game to confirm it, though I might just try it out again. One note, though: the composition of mainframe username is not deduced from the name, but from the draft of an angry (therapeutic) e-mail that secretary composes to the doctor.

Comment: @theUg Sorry, I was unclear on that. I'll edit it.

Comment: I checked it out, and confirmed. Starange that I had logged into the e-mails dozen of times, and never noticed the greeting on top.